# Owl carousel - theme css doesn't apply

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, owl-carousel

I need to add owl carousel to my website.
I followed the instructions and used css for default theme as well.
It worked perfectly. And then suddenly (no change of code) default theme stopped working (no theme on nav)...
I've been trying to fix it but I'm loosing my mind... I even reverted changes to point where i was certain it worked!
And it's not about browser because I even uploaded it on my server...

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Light Coorporation - Photo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="../js/jquery.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.stellar.js" language="javascript">    </script>
    <script src="../js/global.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/owl.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include '../include/fixed_menu.php' ?> 
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-slider-custom">
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="../images/murmur.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:15,
        center: true,
        merge: true,
        responsiveClass:true,
        autoWidth: true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
                mergeFit: true,
                nav:true
            },
            600:{
                items:1,
                mergeFit: true,
                nav:true
            },
            1000:{
                items:1,
                mergeFit: true,
                nav:true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It seems weird that it used to work for a while and then stopped...
Any help would be apprecieated.
Bless!

demo:
"http://bez-granic.eu/lc/photo/"

Comment: It's going to be difficult for us to help without seeing the site. Any 404 errors in the console?

Comment: That is strange. Possibly related: when I refresh the page in Chrome the carousel doesn't initialize correctly--all the images are stacked in a column. No errors are reported.

Comment: I've noticed that too. Have I done sth wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently I've had wrong version of css... It wasn't easy to find proper one but I found it overe here https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel2/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 4):

**In case this helps someone:**
from:http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-classes.html

Notice the class  owl-theme in: `<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">`